# Convert Python dict to Javascript Object and access the key and value

Tags: javascript, python, json

Trying to access just the value or key of the JSON object but it displays as undefined.

Tried to `json.parse` but same results.

```
now = datetime.now()
date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
print(date_time)
chatrooms[chatroom][username][date_time] = message
message = json.dumps(chatrooms[chatroom][username])
emit("append messages", message, broadcast=True)
```

```
socket.on('append messages', data => {
             const li = document.createElement('li');
             // parse the messages;
             var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
             message = `${response.date_time}`;
```

The message that was sent in, but I am getting undefined. I tried ridding of the jQuery Parse, but it is not working.

Comment: 1. add example python output to the question 2. there's no need to parse `data`, it's an object already 3. `message = response.date_time;`

Comment: did you check `data`? does it contain valid json, the entire json and nothing but the json?

Comment: @ChrisG, This is the output from after json.dump
{"07/23/2019, 08:53:53": "hi"}
I removed the  parse and it still reads undefined. My dict in python is nested like so
{'Chatroom': {'Username': {'07/23/2019, 08:53:53': 'hi'}}}

Comment: @Thomas, the json is valid but it is in a json string. meaning that if I did response[0] it will account for the curly brace...I have no way of just attaining the data inside the double quotes.

Comment: OK, this sounds like you have encoded your data twice. I'm not familiar with the python side of the code. Could it be that `emit()` already encodes the passed payload? what happens if you try `emit("append messages", chatrooms[chatroom][username], broadcast=True)`? Sidenote: JSON is **always** a string; it's a serialization format. What you probably have in mind are Object literals.

Comment: @Thomas, if I don't have the dump on the python side, and no parsing on the Javascript side, the result for data is [object Object]. 

I saw on the W3Schools website that if you parse a python dict, it turns into a javascript object...so weird. So if JSON is always a string, that would mean that I need to write my own program to take out the curly braces?

Comment: *"... the result for data is [object Object]"* which sounds pretty good to me, This means that you got your object from the backend *(python would not send this string)* but then you tried to cast/convert the entire object into a string (without serializing it). something like `\`${someObject}\``. check `console.log(data, Object.entries(data)); This should show you the object with its properties and an array of key-value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved the issue, first you have to use json.dumps(foo) from the python side via socketemit and then to convert it to a Javascript Object - you have to again use json.parse(foo). Then it is in an Object literal which can be accessed using a for loop to get at the value and key! Like so

```
  for (var i in foo) {
            var key = i;
            var val = foo[i];
}
```